# Diamond shape with wrapping width and height

Tags: html, css

Okay, so whenever I try to create a diamond the edges of the diamond go out of it's width, and I'm not looking to fix this using margin, I want the actual width and height to change.

Here's how I would create a diamond shape..

```
diamond{
            width:65px;
            height:65px;
            border:3px solid #0E4991;
            transform: rotate(45deg);
        }
```

This is what happens:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFoFZ.png)

How do I fix this?

Comment: @Paulie_D I wan't the width and height the actually wrap around the diamond, it doesn't do it as of now.

Comment: You should wrap it then in another element, so in other words; nest it in a parent element - e.g: `data:text/html,<div class="shape-wrapper"><div class="diamond-shape"></div></div> <style> .diamond-shape { width: 0; height: 0; border: 50px solid transparent; border-bottom-color: red; position: relative; top: -50px; } .diamond-shape:after { content: ''; position: absolute; left: -50px; top: 50px; width: 0; height: 0; border: 50px solid transparent; border-top-color: red; } </style>` (paste all of that in your browser url bar and hit enter)

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError yeah but I don't want a diamond like that, because then I can't have a border around it. can I?

Comment: @Paulie_D I showed a image right

Comment: @CS-CASES.org No, but you can still wrap it in a parent element, can't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an element that is 65px wide/high, when you rotate is the vertical/horizontal dimensions change according... because a transfom is an *entirely* visual effect.

As such, if you need the rotated element to fit into a 65px by 65px space you have to *reduce the size*.

The ratio in question is the square root of 2 = 1.1412

So the new dimensions will be the original values divided by that figure.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;
  margin: 3em auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: relative;
}

.diamond {
  width: calc(100%/1.4142);
  height: calc(100%/1.4142);
  border: 3px solid #0E4991;
  position: absolute;
  ;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="diamond"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't really understand how the square root of 2 makes this work. I'll try it out though, thanks.